# In APB Reloaded, how do I earn virtual currency (other than paying real money) and buy upgrades?

Tags: apb-reloaded

I need to know how to upgrade weapons, armor, etc. I tried searching google and their website, but all I can find is how to buy upgrades. I want to know how I gain money in the game and how to purchase weapons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to buy upgrades. You need to find a character, the ones in the room where you enter in the district, and walk up to them and press "F". Then you can buy upgrades using the virtual currency (as opposed to the other market making you pay money to buy upgrades).

Some of the things I have found so far to acquire more virtual currency as enforcer are:

- finish missions
- kill the enemies
- complete objectives.

I also noticed if you kill pedestrians or your own teammates (even by accident) then you get less rewards.

however, I do not know how to maximize it. I hope someone else can answer better.

Comment: A higher Prestige/Notoriety yields larger rewards.

Comment: You forgot to kill players with a Prestige/Notoriety of 5 and earning medals which boost your reward after missions.